# New Zealand refugee or protection status claims visas

Tags: new-zealand

I live in Iraq. I am Turkish citizen. I was victimized by the Turkish government.

I have a record in the UN. I want to apply for refugee or protection status visa. All my official documents are ready.

Online application option for one person on New Zealand online visa application website but I have a family.

How to apply for the family? What forms do I need to fill out?

There is this option in the New Zealand website
you can look at the picture
but I want to apply within my family
when I choose family
paper comes with option
but I do not know which papers are going to be filled with paper[image]

Comment: I think you have to be in New Zealand to apply for asylum/refugee status.

Comment: @mkennedy it's also possible to apply to UNHCR or perhaps other agencies for resettlement, but I think you're right that you need to be in the country to apply directly to the NZ government.

Comment: Hekim: Can you ask through the support options on the website, or at the [embassy in Baghdad](https://www.mfat.govt.nz/en/countries-and-regions/middle-east/iraq/new-zealand-embassy-baghdad/)?  Can you get support from [UNHCR](http://reporting.unhcr.org/node/2547), or perhaps a non-governmental organization such as the [IRC](https://www.rescue.org/country/iraq) or the [Red Crescent](https://en.ircs.org.iq/)?